# PyQt application crashes using subprocess.call

Tags: python, eclipse, jar, pyqt, osx-elcapitan

I want to execute a .jar file from a python Qt application (I use Python 2.7 and PyQt4).
I launch a subprocess.call within a method connect to a pushbutton event:

```
def pushButtonClickedMethod(self):
    callJar= ['java', '-jar', 'file.jar', arg1, arg2]
    returnCode = subprocess.call(callJar, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

I am running this PyQt application within Eclipse (using PyDev plug-in), over MacOSX El Capitan. The application crashes when executing the subprocess.call and in the eclipse console the returning code is -6. Cannot find what the -6 means.
Is this the best way to execute a .jar file from a PyQt application? Any hints on what can be wrong?

The .jar file is a runnable .jar, created from the same Eclipse. And it is working as expected when I run it on the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks Maurice! I'll try to follow that!

Comment: I leave this link here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57116-SOLVED-QProcess-Java-Application-Not-Working that show the use of QProcess with java -jar